# I am getting the error "TypeError: must be str, not bytes" when appending base64-encoded bytes to a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

Facing error in the line `data_to_send = data + encoded_string`
I am using sockets for communication.

The first function `browse` is to open the explorer to select the file that is to be sent and the second function `multimedia_send()` is the main function which sends the file to the other end. I am trying to read the file as bytes and format the same into strings and pass it over the socket. However I am facing this error:

> TypeError: must be str, not bytes

```
def browse(self):
    self.mmfilename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    self.multimedia_send()

def multimedia_send(self):

    filename = self.mmfilename
    file = open(filename, 'rb')
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(file.read())

    data = "^"
    for client in self.list_of_active_user:
        if self.enable[client].get() == 1:
            data = data + "@" + client + ' '
    data = data + ':'
    data = data + filename + ':'
    data_to_send = data + encoded_string

    self.chat_entry.delete(0, Tkinter.END)#input box empty after send
    self.conn.send(data_to_send.encode())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter_init_.py", line 1699, 
in call return self.func(*args) File ".\client.py", line 295, 
in browse self.multimedia_send() File ".\client.py", line 333, 
in multimedia_send data_to_send = data + encoded_string 
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File ".\client.py", line 295, in browse
    self.multimedia_send()
  File ".\client.py", line 333, in multimedia_send
    data_to_send = data + encoded_string
TypeError: must be str, not bytes

This is the error that Iam getting while sharing the file. Hope I have made my query clear

Comment: What is inside of the for `encoded_string` ? Likely it is not a string type so you cannot add it to another string.

Comment: Please provide the full traceback (EDIT: as an edit to the original question, not an illegible comment) and remove one of the python version tags

Comment: The file that i am trying to send is a simpe notepad file .txt around 2KB in size. The file contains the texts "Hello World"

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure you are running python 2? Can you do a `python -V`?. In python 3, opening a file with `rb` create bytes that base64 happily encode producing also bytes.